# Django-nonrel admin superuser in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-admin, django-nonrel

I have a Django app for which I have created a superuser account for so I can log into django-admin.

This works in local (I can log in).

How do I create a superuser on my appspot.com account on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else with a similar problem: what you need to do is use

```
manage.py remote createsuperuser
```

to create a superuser in GAE